# Visualforce Components with Shared Abstract Class

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have multiple visualforce components that each have their own controller that is extended from a base abstract class. For example:

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page>
    <c:MyFirstComponent />
    <c:MySecondComponent />
...
```

**MyFirstComponent 1:**

`<apex:component controller="MyFirstComponentController">`

**MyFirstComponentController Class:**

`public class MyFirstComponentController extends BaseController {`

**MySecondComponent 2:**

`<apex:component controller="MySecondComponentController">`

**MySecondComponentControllerClass:**

`public class MySecondComponentController extends BaseController {`

**BaseController :**

```
public abstract class BaseController {
    BaseController(){
        getSomeData();  // Here's the problem
    }
}
```

Right now for every component instance on the page a BaseController instance is constructed causing the `getSomeData()` method to fire but this is not necessary considering the data is the same for all components on the page. What is the best way to avoid this?

I was thinking perhaps to remove the controller from the components themselves and instead add those controllers as extensions on the page which I would then pass their instance as an attribute to each component... but since each extension extends the `BaseController` I would still have duplicates for every component type I have on the page.

Is there a different structure I could use to allow for this without causing these redundancy issues?

Comment: +1 for titling the post such that it is likely to be found again by others with the same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use a CommonDataController to pass this data around:

```
public class CommonDataController {
    public CommonDataController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        getSomeData();
    }
    public CommonDataController getCommonData() {
        return this;
    }
    // getSomeData not relevant to this example, but should exist.
}
```

In your BaseController, provide a holding place for this:

```
public abstract class BaseController {
    protected CommonDataController commonData;
    public void setCommonDataController(CommonDataController data) {
        commonData = data;
    }
    public CommonDataController getCommonDataController() {
        return commonData;
    }
}
```

Then, your page just includes CommonDataController once:

```
<apex:page ... extensions="CommonDataController">
    ... <c:myWidget commonData="{!commonData}" /> ...
```

And each component uses that data:

```
<apex:component ...>
    <apex:attribute name="commonData" assignTo="{!commonDataController}" type="CommonDataController" description="..." required="true" />
```

At this point, you have non-static data populated from a common point that allows inter-component communications, shared data resources, etc. The constructor is called only once, and each extension class is provided access to the common data.

Comment: Getting the following error when attempting to deploy the component: `Error: Read only property 'c:myWidget.commonDataController'`

Comment: @Xtremefaith It might need to be all marked up as global instead of public. I did have that problem previously.

Comment: I added global to the base controller class and replaced the protected `commonData` with global but still getting the read only property...

Comment: @Xtremefaith Hold on. It's in my one of my dev orgs. I'll update this answer in a bit.

Comment: I switched `commonData` to public and added `{ get; set; }` and now its working...

Comment: @Xtremefaith That wasn't meant to be public. I think you got confused by some names in there. The point was to bind to `getCommonData` on the page. However, there's nothing particularly wrong with binding to it directly.